# Does uninstalling Redis clear its memory data?

Tags: redis, centos, yum

I am on CentOS 7 and I uninstall Redis by doing `yum remove redis`.

How can I be sure that the memory is cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before un-installing redis. Clear all keys from redis and shutdown redis-server using redis-cli:

```
redis-cli> FLUSHALL
redis-cli> SHUTDOWN
```

https://redis.io/commands/flushall

This will clean up all data from redis to release the memory

You can uninstall redis once cleanup is done and the redis process is stopped:

`yum remove redis`

Comment: Thanks, what I am asking is if I uninstalled before flushing, will it get flushed automatically?

Comment: if you remove redis using yum, the process will be not stopped, it will keep running and holding the memory. You need to manually stop the redis process and then perform yum remove redis. Your data will not be flushed automatically if you do uninstall before